# Database design for a forum

Tags: mysql, hierarchy

I am trying to build a forum kind of like reddit. Discussions can have comments and people can comment on comments. My solution for such a hierarchical database is to use a closure table for my comments.
This is my database design so far.

[image]

Lets say I have the following posts(order here shows if it's a first reply, second etc):

```
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
| post        | PARENT               | ORDER  |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
|           A | NULL                 |      1 |
|           B | A                    |      1 |
|           C | A                    |      2 |
|           D | B                    |      1 |
|           E | B                    |      2 |
+-------------+----------------------+--------+
```

When I query the closure table I get the posts in depth order. So I get a result likes this on the frontend:

```
A
 B
 C
  D
  E
```

However I would like to get the following order since E AND D are children of B:

```
A
 B
  D
  E
 C
```

I just added this post_hierarchy table to keep track of the order of each comment (e.g. first reply, second reply..). However I am no sure how to combine the query of the closure table with a query of the post_hierarchy table to get the desired result?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thanks

Comment: Why the different data types for the `parent` (`varchar` and `smallint`) and `child` (`smallint`) fields vs the `id` (`int`) fields, which is what I assume they relate to? This could cause potential performance issues.

Comment: its a type... the parent is a reference to post

Comment: Not following you...Do you join `parent` to `id`?

Comment: Its a manytomany relation column for parent_id

Comment: I don't see `parent_id` anywhere in your picture. If that's another table that's not currently depicted, then you should add the definition of that table to your post as well.